# Select row at random based on the "weight" of that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have a table like this:

```
ID chance
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 1
```

Now I need to choose a rand() from this table

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

But ID #2 has double the chances to be selected compared to ID #1 AND 4. Likewise ID #3 has four times the chances to be selected compared to ID #1 AND 4.

Somewhat similar to lottery based on chance.

Comment: *sorry for my pure engilsh* yeah it's fine

Comment: could you please [edit] your question and add sample how you use 'rand()'

Answer (score 2):

This is how lottery works in some of the games. Given table similar to your example (say, we also have `chance` column that indicated value-based possibility of getting this particular reward), the algorithm is:

1. Calculate total lottery value (in your example it is `1 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 8`).
2. Generate a value that is from range `1..max` (`max` is `8` in current example) inclusive.
3. Iterate over all items from rewards list to find the one item where sum of all previous chances is more than generated number but less or equal than

Say, we have generated number `5`. Our comparison steps are:

1. `0 < 5 <= (0) + 1` is false so ID1 is not what we get. Left side is 0 because we start our calculations from 0.
2. `1 < 5 <= (1) + 2` is false so ID2 is not what we get.
3. `1 + 2 < 5 <= (1 + 2) + 4` is true so we get ID3.

Example in JavaScript:

```js
var rewards = [
  { id: 1, chance: 1 },
  { id: 2, chance: 2 },
  { id: 3, chance: 4 },
  { id: 4, chance: 1 }
];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generate() {
  var sum = 0;
  var next_sum = 0;
  var random = getRandomInt(1, rewards.reduce(function(pv, cv) {
    return pv + cv.chance;
  }, 0));

  for (var i = 0; i < rewards.length; i++) {
    next_sum = sum + rewards[i].chance;
    if ((random > sum) && (random <= next_sum)) {
      return rewards[i].id;
    }
    sum += rewards[i].chance;
  }
}

var winnerCounts = {}, i, winner;
for (i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
  winner = generate();
  winnerCounts[winner] = (winnerCounts[winner] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log("Number of times each id was selected after %d itrations", i);
console.log(winnerCounts);
```

Comment: @x-rw the algorithm has nothing to do with machine learning, at least not intended to

Answer (score 2):

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/827369/45) with a MySQL-only solution

```
select * from (
  select id, @running_total as previous_total, @running_total := @running_total + chance AS running_total, until.rand
  from (
    select round(rand() * init.max) as rand from (
      select sum(chance) - 1 as max from demo
    ) as init
  ) as until,
  demo,
  ( select @running_total := 0.00 ) as vars
) as results
where results.rand >= results.previous_total and results.rand < results.running_total
```

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Find out the sum of all the chances and store it in `max`
2. Generate a random number in the interval `[0, max)`
3. For every row, compute a `previous_total (initially 0)` and a `current_total` of the chances encountered so far
4. Keep only the row where the generated number is in the interval `[previous_total, current_total)`

Because we have an even chance to pick each number in the interval `[0, sum_of_all_chances)`, then we can asign every entry as many numbers in this interval as it has chances to get picked, ensuring an even distribution.

`@running_total` is just a MySQL variable and I have used `( select @running_total := 0.00 ) as vars` only as a way to give it an initial value. 
Also, I have used `(
    select round(rand() * init.max) as rand from (
      select sum(chance) - 1 as max from demo
    ) as init
  ) as until` just as a way to sum up the chances and store the random number generated by MySQL's `rand` function. Hope this makes the code easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you need in clear MySQL solution you can use this:

> SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY -LOG(1-RAND())/chance LIMIT 1

Here is about choosing a random number from the exponential distribution
http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/0806%20generate%20random%20numbers.shtml

Simple code **"just for test"**

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY -LOG(1-RAND())/chance LIMIT 1";
$Res=array();
for ($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (isset($row['id'])) {
       echo "$i. => ".($row['id'])."\n";
       if (!isset($Res[$row['id']])) $Res[$row['id']]=0;
       $Res[$row['id']]++;
    } else {
        echo ' error.432 ';exit;
    }
}

print_r($Res);
```

You will see that "2" twice more often than "4" or "1". And "3" twice more often than "2"